# Run multiple jobs on same slurm worker in parallel

Tags: linux

We have some fairly fat nodes in our SLURM cluster (e.g. 14 cores). I'm trying to configure it such that multiple batch jobs can be run in parallel, each requesting, for example, 3 cores. However, I can't get that to work.

Example batch job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=job1
#SBATCH --output=job1.txt
#
#SBATCH -c 3
#SBATCH -N 1
srun sleep 300
srun echo $HOSTNAME
```

Excerpt from the slurm.conf file:

```
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_CORE
NodeName=some-node NodeAddr=192.168.60.106 CPUs=12 State=UNKNOWN
```

But, if I run the two jobs, I get the following error:

> sbatch: error: CPU count per node can not be satisfied

I found quite a few examples where it sais the `sbatch -n` option is what controls the amount of CPUs or cores per batch job, however, that does not make sense to me since the documentation states:

> Controls the number of tasks to be created for the job

If I try, it it just runs the jobs sequentially:

> ```
>          JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
>             16  mainpart     job2  some-user PD       0:00      1 (Resources)
>             15  mainpart     job1  some-user  R       4:04      1 some-node
> ```

Comment: Did you configure your nodes correctly? What does `scontrol show node=<node-name>` or `sinfo -Nel` return?

Comment: The `SBATCH -c 3` part is what controls the amount of processors per task

Comment: @Thomas That pointed me in the right direction. It only showed 1 cpu per node because hwloc was not installed when I compiled it. After recompilation it does now show 28 CPUs and 1:14:2 (S:C:T). The only thing now is that hyperthreads are consumed with -c instead of cores but I can live with that for now or disable it in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem for days with SLURM running only one job per node no matter what I put into the batch files. The following combination of settings finally allowed me to get multiple batches running on a single node.

Before starting, ensure there are no jobs running and drop your nodes. See [this answer for more on service vs systemctl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903354/difference-between-systemctl-and-service) for doing so on most linux systems.

```
sudo service slurmd stop
sudo service slurmctld stop
```

In /etc/slurm-llnl/slurm.conf (location may differ)

```
...
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
...
NodeName=a NodeAddr=192.168.1.2 CPUs=16 Sockets=2 CoresPerSocket=4 ThreadsPerCore=2 RealMemory=12005 State=UNKNOWN
```

This is obviously specific to one particular node, and yours will differ. But if the node is not configured correctly, SLURM can return errors about resources being unavailable. To get reliable information about your node, try the following on each node:

```
sudo slurmd -C
```

Then use its output to define each node in the controller's slurm.conf file. When things are set up, start SLURM back up again and send it some test batches to see if they spread out across the nodes properly.

```
sudo service slurmd start
sudo service slurmctld start
```